# How do you set up an array in Experian's PowerCurve Script?

Tags: dsl

Experian's PowerCurve software has an internal scripting language. The documentation on this software is limited and I can't figure out how or even if it's possible to implement an array.

How do you set up an array or something similar in Experian's PowerCurve script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the GDU and set the array size for the variable in question.